# if-else syntax error (Pizza delivery problem)

Tags: python, if-statement

```
print('Welcome to Python Pizza Deliveries!')
size = input('What size pizza do you want? S, M, or L? ').lower()
add_pepperoni = input('Do you want to add perperoni? Y or N? ').lower()
extra_cheese = input('Do you want to add extra cheese? Y or N? ').lower()
bill = 0
if size == 's':
    bill = 15 
    if add_pepperoni == 'y':
        bill += 2
elif size == 'm':
    bill = 20
    if add_pepperoni == 'y':
        bill += 3
elif size == 'l':
    bill = 25
    if add_pepperoni =='y':
        bill += 3

if extra_cheese == 'y':
    bill += 1
print(f'Your total bill is ${bill}.')
else :
    print('Invalid Response.')
```

I don't know why I am getting a syntax error at the last else statement. I wanted to add an Invalid response as an option but where I am getting it wrong?
I am getting this

```
File "<ipython-input-202-1b45bbcb6bb4>", line 22
    else :
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` statement should be indented under the `if`. With the current indentation, you have an `if` statement followed by a `print` call, followed by a "dangling" `else` that isn't associated to any `if` - which is of course incorrect syntax:

```py
if extra_cheese == 'y':
    bill += 1
    print(f'Your total bill is ${bill}.')
else :
    print('Invalid Response.')
```

Comment: Thank you! It was easy.. but it never showed me indentation error so I didn't move them around much. Now I got that!